# How to put a JavaScript function in an HTML onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

Hello I would like to put my JavaScript function in an onclick html because I have several exercises on my page

`<button type="button" onclick="formatTime()">Click</button>`

Comment: and, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem here, make sure you link you're javascript correctly.

Comment: What is your question? With the code provided clicking the button will execute the function `formatTime()`. Was there something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your button should call the javascript function formatTime() onclick, there is nothing wrong with the HTML. Does the Chrome/Firefox Developer Console output any errors on click?
See [here](https://codepen.io/hendrikwegner/pen/RmbEMV) for an example.

```
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">click</button>
<script>
function foo() {
    alert('hello world');
}
</script>
```